# Natural transformations between coterminal functors with differing domains

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose we have categories and functors as below

[image]

We can still talk about a 'natural transformation' $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$ as consisting of a collection of arrows $\{\alpha_X:F(X)\to G(X)\}_{X\in{\bf Ob}_\mathcal{C}}$ such that

[image]

commutes for all arrows $f:X\to Y\in{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}$.

> Have generalizations of natural transformations for coterminal functors with related domains been studied? What names do these notions go by?

This comes up (for example) studying [institutions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/institution); recall that an institution $\mathbb{I}$ consists of:

1. A category ${\bf Sig}$ called the *category of $\mathbb{I}$-signatures*.
2. A functor $${\sf Sen}:{\bf Sig}\to{\bf Set}$$ assigning to each signature $\Sigma$ a set ${\sf Sen}(\Sigma)$ whose elements are called *sentences over $\Sigma$*.
3. A functor $${\sf Mod}:{\bf Sig}^{op}\to{\bf Cat}$$ assigning to each signature $\Sigma$ a category ${\sf Mod}(\Sigma)$ whose objects are called *$\Sigma$-models* and whose arrows are called *$\Sigma$-model homomorphisms*.
4. A collection of relations $\{\models_\Sigma:{\bf Ob}_{{\sf Mod}(\Sigma)}\to{\sf Sen}(\Sigma)\}_{\Sigma\in{\bf Ob}_{\bf Sig}}$ called *$\Sigma$-satisfaction*, such that the following diagram
   [image]
   commutes for all $\varphi:\Sigma\to\Sigma'\in{\bf Hom}_{\bf Sig}$. The requirement that these diagrams commute is called the *satisfaction condition* for $\mathbb{I}$.

Recall that any indexed category $P:\mathcal{C}\to\mathfrak{Cat}$ gives rise to an 'object part presheaf' $${\bf Ob}_P:\mathcal{C}\to{\bf Set}$$ $$X\mapsto{\bf Ob}_{P(X)},$$ $$f:X\to Y\longmapsto P(f)_0:{\bf Ob}_{P(X)}\to{\bf Ob}_{P(Y)}.$$ Recall further that any set-valued functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to{\bf Set}$ can be trivially extended to a relation-valued functor $F^{\leftrightarrow}:\mathcal{C}\to{\bf Rel}$ by postcomposing with the canonical inclusion ${\bf Set}\hookrightarrow{\bf Rel}$. Then the satisfaction condition is just naturality for a 'natural transformation' $$\models\;:{\bf Ob}_{\sf Mod}^{\leftrightarrow}\Rightarrow{\sf Sen}^{\leftrightarrow}.$$ This situation is obviously leveraging the fact that ${\bf Ob}_\mathcal{C}={\bf Ob}_{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$ and ${\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}\cong{\bf Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$, and it's pretty easy to generalize further to "natural transformations" between coterminal functors with equivalent domains, but I'm almost sure this is already generalized by something in the literature. [Extranatural transformations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation) and [dinatural transformations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation) didn't seem to fit the bill on the face of it, but I haven't really worked with either notion and it's certainly possible that I'm just not seeing how to interpret these transformations as appropriately extra/dinatural. Any pointers or references are appreciated.

Comment: See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation , especially the second item in "Special Cases".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah, thank you -- if you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I don't think the translation of the "satisfaction condition" into the form at the top of the question is correct. For example there may be sentences over $\Sigma'$ which are not in the image of the sentences over $\Sigma$, but are still satisfied by models of $\Sigma'$. Instead it should be an equality between two relations from models of $\Sigma'$ to sentences over $\Sigma$ (or vice versa), which is an ordinary natural transformation once we transpose one of the two functors.

Comment: @ReidBarton The formulation at the top is not a translation, I copied it directly from Diaconescu's book [Institution Independent Model Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-7643-8708-2) -- the suggestion that it can be reformulated as a natural transformation is my 'translation' of his formulation. Are you saying that you think his characterization is wrong but the natural transformation characterization fixes it?

Comment: What I mean is that the "commutative diagram" cannot be understood as an equality between a relation and a composition of three relations (two of which are functions). It must be understood as an equality between two compositions of two relations (in each of which, one relation is a function read in either the forwards or backwards direction). Therefore, it does not fit into the form found in "We can still talk about a 'natural transformation'..."

Comment: @ReidBarton I finally understood your comment, and you are correct that extending ${\sf Sen}$ to be relation valued and transposing it (and observing that ${\bf Rel}^{op}={\bf Rel}$) allows us to formulate satisfaction as a regular natural transformation; thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer, as suggested by OP: This is a special case of dinatural transformations. See, for example, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation , especially the second item in "Special Cases".